# What is the impact of the not creating a primary key to a table in Redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift

What is the impact of the not creating a primary key to a table in Redshift , especially on tables that record the web logs of 1tb size?

Answer (score 0):

In Redshift, a primary key MAY be useful if you need it for queries, for example referring to the primary key when joining to another table.

However, there is no other benefit. If you don't need it for queries then you don't need it and it serves no other purpose.

The impact of removing it - it will reduce the amount of storage space consumed a little, however it wont speed up any queries that do not need it!

Removing it may affect tools such as DMS (if you use that)

Comment: okay ., is it a good design to not define primary keys to a table ?

Answer (score 0):

Primary/Unique and Foreign Keys can impact the query plan and in some cases result in performance gains. The Keys are not enforced by Redshift but it makes the assumption that they are correct. If the keys are incorrect and the plan assumes uniqueness this could result in different results. Only use Key Constraints when your upstream systems will not cause key constraint violations.